# While Loop multiple choice what is value of increment index

Tags: python

For this while loop in Python:

```
def last_vowel(s):   
    Return the last vowel in s if one exists; otherwise, return None.

    i = ________
    while i >= 0:
         if s[i] in 'aeiouAEIOU':
             return s[i]
         i = i - 1
   return None
```

The question is to find i's expression, which turns out to be len(s) - 1 rather than len(s). Can anyone explain to me why this is so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because strings (and arrays, as strings are just special arrays really) are 0 indexed. This means that although a string may have a length of `L`, the last item will actually be `L - 1`.

For example, take this string

```
"hello"
```

It has length of 5, but the last character is actually at index 4.

```
+-------+---+---+---+---+---+
| index | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
+-------+---+---+---+---+---+
| char  | h | e | l | l | o |
+-------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's indexing is `0` based. So the first character in a `string` is at index `0`, and the last one before the length of the `string`. See this small table:

```
String: "hello"
Index :  01234
```

See how the last character is at index `4` - which is `len(...) - 1`!

---

So, this explains why we need to initialise `i` as `len(s) - 1` as the `s[len(s) - 1]` is the *last* character in `s`.

The algorithm then says too check this character to see if it is a vowel, if it is, `return` the vowel, otherwise decrease `i` by `1` so that for the next loop of the `while` we are looking at the previous character.

Then for this character, we apply the same methods.

Finally, the function will have either returned the vowel closest to the end, or will reach the end of the `while` loop (`i == 0`) and will `return None` as described by the functionality of the function.